# Error al intentar ejecutar funcion - No me retorna nada

Tags: python

he estado tratando de hacer este problema pero cuando corro mi funcion no me retorna nada. Alguien sabe porque sera?

Este es el problema:

Iván, Nicolás, y Adriana son amigos de toda la vida. A los 3 les gusta comer uvas, por lo que se reúnen cada semana, en la tarde del viernes, para hablar de su semana y disfrutar de ese deleite. Iván, Nicolás y Adriana comen una cierta cantidad entera de uvas, que puede o no ser igual entre ellos. Además, ellos siempre compran 3 tipos de uvas: Verde, Negra y Morada. Ellos ordenan las uvas con una semana de anticipación, y las reciben por domicilio. Esto implica que, algunas veces, los amigos pueden no tener suficientes uvas para satisfacer sus gustos. Ellos no saben predecir cuantas uvas querrán con exactitud semana tras semana.

De los amigos, se sabe además que:

- Iván come exclusivamente uvas verdes
- Nicolás odia las uvas negras, por lo que solamente come uvas verdes o moradas
- Adriana come cualquier tipo de uva, pues todas le encantan

Los tres amigos quieren saber si, dadas unas cantidades de uvas negras, verdes, y -moradas que llegan en el pedido, podrán quedar felices dada la cantidad de uvas que quieran comer en el día. Nótese que ellos quieren que la mayor cantidad de amigos logre comerse todas las uvas que quiere. En otras palabras, un amigo puede decidir no comer uvas siempre que dicha decisión le permita a alguien más completar su cantidad.

codigo:

```
def suficientes_uvas(cantidad_ivan: int, cantidad_nicolas: int, cantidad_adriana: int, cantidad_verde: int, cantidad_morada: int, cantidad_negra: int)->str:

    cantidad_contentos = 0
    
    if cantidad_ivan <= cantidad_nicolas and cantidad_ivan <= cantidad_adriana:
        
        if cantidad_verde >= cantidad_ivan:
            cantidad_contentos += 1
            cantidad_verde = cantidad_verde - cantidad_ivan
            
        if cantidad_nicolas <= cantidad_adriana:
            if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada >= cantidad_nicolas):
                cantidad_contentos += 1
            
                if cantidad_verde < cantidad_nicolas:
                    cantidad_nicolas -= cantidad_verde
                    cantidad_verde = 0
                    cantidad_morada -= cantidad_nicolas
                else:
                    cantidad_verde -= cantidad_nicolas
                    
            if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada + cantidad_negra >= cantidad_adriana):
                cantidad_contentos += 1
            
        else:
        
            if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada + cantidad_negra >= cantidad_adriana):
                cantidad_contentos += 1
                
                if cantidad_negra < cantidad_adriana:
                    cantidad_adriana -= cantidad_negra
                    cantidad_negra=0
                    
                    if cantidad_morada < cantidad_adriana:
                        cantidad_adriana -= cantidad_morada
                        cantidad_morada = 0
                        cantidad_verde -= cantidad_adriana
                else:
                    cantidad_negra -= cantidad_adriana
            
            if (cantidad_verde+ cantidad_morada >= cantidad_nicolas):
                cantidad_contentos += 1
                
    elif cantidad_nicolas <= cantidad_ivan and cantidad_nicolas <= cantidad_adriana:
        if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada >= cantidad_nicolas):
             cantidad_contentos += 1
                    
             if cantidad_morada < cantidad_nicolas:
                  cantidad_nicolas -= cantidad_morada
                  cantidad_morada= 0
                  cantidad_verde -= cantidad_nicolas
             else:
                  cantidad_morada -= cantidad_nicolas
                   
        if cantidad_ivan <= cantidad_adriana:
             
            if cantidad_verde >= cantidad_ivan:
                cantidad_contentos += 1
                cantidad_verde = cantidad_verde - cantidad_ivan
                        
            if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada + cantidad_negra >= cantidad_adriana):
                    cantidad_contentos += 1
        else:
                
            if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada + cantidad_negra >= cantidad_adriana):
                cantidad_contentos += 1
                    
                if cantidad_negra < cantidad_adriana:
                    cantidad_adriana -= cantidad_negra
                    cantidad_negra=0
                    if cantidad_morada<cantidad_adriana:
                        cantidad_adriana -= cantidad_morada
                        cantidad_morada = 0
                        cantidad_verde -= cantidad_adriana
                else:
                    cantidad_negra -= cantidad_adriana
                    
            if cantidad_verde >= cantidad_ivan:
                cantidad_contentos += 1
                
            else:
                    
                if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada + cantidad_negra >= cantidad_adriana):
                    cantidad_contentos += 1
                    if cantidad_negra < cantidad_adriana:
                        cantidad_adriana -= cantidad_negra
                        cantidad_negra = 0
                        if cantidad_morada < cantidad_adriana:
                            cantidad_adriana -= cantidad_morada
                            cantidad_morada = 0
                            cantidad_verde -= cantidad_adriana
                            
                    else:
                        cantidad_negra -= cantidad_adriana
                        
                if cantidad_nicolas <= cantidad_ivan:
                
                    if cantidad_verde >= cantidad_ivan:
                        cantidad_contentos += 1
                        cantidad_verde = cantidad_verde - cantidad_ivan
                
                    if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada >= cantidad_nicolas):
                        cantidad_contentos += 1
                else:
                
                    if (cantidad_verde + cantidad_morada >= cantidad_nicolas):
                        cantidad_contentos += 1
                        if cantidad_morada < cantidad_nicolas:
                            cantidad_nicolas -= cantidad_morada
                            cantidad_morada= 0
                            cantidad_verde -= cantidad_nicolas
                        else:
                            cantidad_morada -= cantidad_nicolas
                
                    if cantidad_verde >= cantidad_ivan:
                        cantidad_contentos += 1 
                        cantidad_verde = cantidad_verde - cantidad_ivan
                
                            
            if cantidad_contentos == 0:
                rta = "al menos somos amigos"
            elif cantidad_contentos == 1:
                rta = "fallamos"
            elif cantidad_contentos == 2:
                rta = "casi"
            else:
                rta = "felices"
                        
            return rta
```

Comment: En `Python` la indentación es muy importante, no sé si todos los `if`, `elif` y `else` estén correctamente indentados pero al probar con `suficientes_uvas(5,5,5,5,5,5)` entra en el primer `if` y ahí no tienes ningún `return` por eso no devuelve nada.

Answer (score 3):

[Nota: Colocar este código dentro de una función queda de tarea para el OP]

Propongo una solución corta basada en un algoritmo de "remate". La idea es que cada uva sera rematada al mejor postor: aquel que tenga más interés y menor cantidad de uvas acumuladas.

#### Modelamiento

Modelare las uvas como enteros: verde=0, negra=1, morada=2.

El pedido recibido será guardado en `delivery` como una secuencia de digitos (0,1,2), cada uno representando una uva.

Modelare las preferencias de cada persona como una lista de enteros, donde a mayor valor, mayor interés por esa uva. Igualmente, el valor cero implica rechazo. En esta lista las preferencias están en orden [verde, negra, morada].

Las preferencias las guardo en este diccionario, con llave nombre de la persona:

```
prioridad = {
    'ivan': [100, 0, 0],
    'nico': [50, 0, 50],
    'adri': [33, 33, 33]
}
```

Finalmente tendré un diccionario con el total de uvas asignadas actualmente a la persona:

```
totales = {
    'ivan': 0,
    'nico': 0,
    'adri': 0
}
```

#### Algoritmo

```
print("Uva  Seleccionado   Totales")
for uva in delivery:
    idx = int(uva)
    print(f" {'VNM'[int(uva)]}   ", end='')
    #   Formar una lista de las personas ordenadas según
    #   su preferencia por esta uva. No incluye personas
    #   que rechazan esta uva. 
    preferencias = sorted((x for x in prioridad.items() if x[1][idx]), key=lambda x: -x[1][idx])
    #   Siempre habrá al menos una persona que desee esta uva.
    #   Seleccionar la persona con menos uvas de la lista
    persona = preferencias[0][0]
    total = totales[persona]
    for p in preferencias:
        if totales[p[0]] < total:
            persona = p[0]
            total = totales[persona]
    totales[persona] += 1
    print(f"{persona}           {totales}")
```

Demo

```
# Codigo v, n, m
delivery = "20002221101221122000"

prioridad = {
    'ivan': [100, 0, 0],
    'nico': [50, 0, 50],
    'adri': [33, 33, 33]
}

totales = {
    'ivan': 0,
    'nico': 0,
    'adri': 0
}

print("Uva  Seleccionado   Totales")
for uva in delivery:
    idx = int(uva)
    print(f" {'VNM'[int(uva)]}   ", end='')
    #   Formar una lista de las personas ordenadas según
    #   su preferencia por esta uva. No incluye personas
    #   que rechazan esta uva.
    preferencias = sorted((x for x in prioridad.items() if x[1][idx]), key=lambda x: -x[1][idx])
    #   Siempre habrá al menos una persona que desee esta uva.
    #   Seleccionar la persona con menos uvas de la lista
    persona = preferencias[0][0]
    total = totales[persona]
    for p in preferencias:
        if totales[p[0]] < total:
            persona = p[0]
            total = totales[persona]
    totales[persona] += 1
    print(f"{persona}           {totales}")
```

produce:

```
Uva  Seleccionado   Totales
 M   nico           {'ivan': 0, 'nico': 1, 'adri': 0}
 V   ivan           {'ivan': 1, 'nico': 1, 'adri': 0}
 V   adri           {'ivan': 1, 'nico': 1, 'adri': 1}
 V   ivan           {'ivan': 2, 'nico': 1, 'adri': 1}
 M   nico           {'ivan': 2, 'nico': 2, 'adri': 1}
 M   adri           {'ivan': 2, 'nico': 2, 'adri': 2}
 M   nico           {'ivan': 2, 'nico': 3, 'adri': 2}
 N   adri           {'ivan': 2, 'nico': 3, 'adri': 3}
 N   adri           {'ivan': 2, 'nico': 3, 'adri': 4}
 V   ivan           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 3, 'adri': 4}
 N   adri           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 3, 'adri': 5}
 M   nico           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 4, 'adri': 5}
 M   nico           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 5, 'adri': 5}
 N   adri           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 5, 'adri': 6}
 N   adri           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 5, 'adri': 7}
 M   nico           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 6, 'adri': 7}
 M   nico           {'ivan': 3, 'nico': 7, 'adri': 7}
 V   ivan           {'ivan': 4, 'nico': 7, 'adri': 7}
 V   ivan           {'ivan': 5, 'nico': 7, 'adri': 7}
 V   ivan           {'ivan': 6, 'nico': 7, 'adri': 7}

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

es la indentación al final. los condicionales que definen rta y su retorno estan dentro del condicional final de las cantidades (donde nicolas quiere comer menos que ivan y etc). La definicion de rta y su retorno deberian estar más a la izquierda para ser parte de la función, no de ese único condicional.

Comment: Hola Shadow Blitz274, bienvenido, gracias por tu aporte, Mira [como responder](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) para evitar votos negativos y/o que tu repuesta sea eliminada.  Aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primer medalla!

Comment: Esto parece realmente un comentario mas que una respuesta. Con un poco mas de reputación, [vas a poder comentar en cualquier lado.](//es.stackoverflow.com/privileges/comment). Por favor mira [answer]